# Handler to fire for mouse click but not enter key?

Tags: css, reactjs, accessibility

For accessibility, you can use the keyboard to tab through interactive elements on a page and hit enter to "click" the selected element. In this case, enter fires `onClick`. Great.

But is there any way to separate these? We would like to disable the focus outline when a button is clicked -- once the button is selected, it turns blue, but the focus outline messes up the look we're going for.

We're using `styled-components`, and we've tried:

```css
outline: 2px solid ${p => (!p.selected ? white : "transparent")};
```

But if a button has been selected (There are many many buttons on the page) and the user is using their keyboard to tab through the buttons, we want a selected button to be outlined when it's focused as part of this tabbing through.

So instead I've set the click handler to `blur` the button after it's clicked.

```js
const PropButton = ({ onClick, ...props }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <S.PropsOfferOption
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      onClick={() => {
        onClick();
        ref.current?.blur();
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This works great. You can tab through the buttons with the keyboard and they have the outline.

The one caveat is that if you click the button by hitting enter, there is no outline. Indeed this is the point of what we wanted to do in the first place, but we were thinking about mouse clicks.

If there were an `onClick` that truly was only for clicking and **not** for enter, we could `blur` here and not in the `onEnter` version. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this code only to achieve a desired visual design? Why not use a border instead of outline on the selected element? If that doesn't work, could `focus-visible` help you without needing to reach for JS? Also, where is the focus moved after the button is blurred? Users without a mouse could get lost after they click the button if the focus is not "rescued" to an appropriate place on the page where they can reorient themselves.

Comment: `onkeydown()` is for keyboard events.  `click()` (not `onclick()`) is for mouse clicks.  `onclick()` is a convenience handler so that you don't have to worry how the user selected the element.

Comment: +1 for a CSS solution with `:focus-visible`. You shouldn't need JS at all for the functionality you're after, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Calling blur() is always a bad idea, don't use it. IF you really need to separate keyboard from mouse, use onkeydown/up vs. onmousedown/up. CSS question: How about the :active pseudo-class ? Isn't it supposed to match precisely when the button is held down ?

Comment: Agree - for the focus rectangle you should use CSS and not JS, as some keyboard or AT users may even have JS disabled in their browser (not common but it's worth considering).